# Angular test case for a component extending base component

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

When I am running a default testcase for a component I am getting this error.
 My component extends another class.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParent' of undefined
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your component code for better understanding? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error is not related to extending the base class. You do not need to do anything special in unit tests if your class is extending any other class.

See there must be some form control or form group in the component that may be left uninitialised. This error arises when form control object is null and html is trying to access the control object.

Comment: True I found the mistake later, it was to do with one of the @Input not initialised.

Comment: Yeah, and the Input() was form control? or something else?

Comment: Yeah it is a form control @Input() control:FormControl

Comment: Is there any thing else expected to be added in the answer to be an accepted answer?